# workingSet command doesn't show output

Tags: mongodb, working-set

I don't know whether I am doing it right or wrong, so let me explain:

I am working on MongoDB version 2.6.6

I have sharded environment, which consists of 2 shards (replica sets), mongos & config servers.

To check out my working set I gave command:

`db.runCommand({serverStatus:1, workingSet:1})`

as shown in the MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/). But there was no `workingSet` document in given output. It returned only `serverStatus` document. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Note: please bear without output as servers are down for maintenance purpose. Hence I really can't provide with the output, but you can guess the output which doesn't include workingSet document.

Comment: Where did you run the `serverStatus` command? On a mongos? On a shard?

Comment: `serverStatus` is per process, not for the cluster, so you got information about the mongos. If you look at the memory numbers I bet they will be suspiciously small. mongos has no working set. Try running `serverStatus` on the mongod's in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

May be not applicable to your version, but Starting in MongoDB 3.0, serverStatus no longer outputs the workingSet, indexCounters, and recordStats sections.